# Docker: use app - Skype from container instead of host

Tags: arch-linux, docker, skype, container

I want to maintain host machine that installed `docker` with minimal packages as possible - I'm using `archlinux` that is rolling-based system, currently I have `142` packages.

But when I'm at work, I still want to use `arch` but some softwares are a must-to-use when working with others, for example: `Skype` - that involve access to `camera` and `microphone` - hardware level of host and possible some ports need to open.

For the particular case that is `Skype` how to install it in a container using `docker` and give it full functions as if it's installed on host? So that whenever I want to use `Skype` I just need to login to container and start to use it?

Comment: Interfacing with hardware devices isn't Docker's strong suit, but I did find a couple of images to run Skype in a container: [1](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-skype), [2](https://github.com/mfehlhaber/docker-skype-pulseaudio).

Comment: I've just seen that `Skype` supports web UI, so I think I'm good now, even install `Pulseaudio` would burden my package management.